# Use Feature ID from Google Maps url in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If a place is selected on [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/), either from the map itself or from the dropdown in a search, on Google Maps, the url looks like this:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Starbucks/@55.6767263,12.5666291,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x4652530e00cbee81:0x5e1ce2a9639f9705
```

After reading [this blog article](https://moz.com/blog/new-google-maps-url-parameters) about the URL parameters, the `/data` part contains a wide range of information, among them is the Feature ID of the selected place. From the url example it's `0x4652530e00cbee81:0x5e1ce2a9639f9705`.

I can look up the Feature ID on Google Mapmaker like this:

```
http://www.google.com/mapmaker?gw=39&fid=0x4652530e00cbee81:0x5e1ce2a9639f9705
```

There it displays the location with no problem.

Is it possible to also use the Feature ID in Google Maps API and display the location?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use Feature ID to display locations in Google Maps API. Based on the [Data.Feature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.Feature) class, it seems to be more used for styling and data layers.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe you are right. I tried to use the 'getFeatureById()' from the 'Data'-class, but it only gets Features which are added locally.
I just wish there was a simple way to get the coordinates of a searched location, weather it's a  place or an address. But I haven't been able to find a method yet.