# Get Location from Feature ID of Search Area from URL Google Map API or SDK?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the location (Lat, Long) from the shared location URL from Google Maps (web, ios android) devices. I am using google shorten [API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#expand) to expand the short URL. Sometimes it gives me long URL which contains Location Information like this URL

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pearl+Continental+Hotel+Lahore/@31.5526078,74.3361773,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x391904c8606da7e9:0xd70a28b88f7720d7!8m2!3d31.5526078!4d74.338366
```

But it sometimes returns other URL which doesn't contain location information especially from Android devices but contains Feature ID of search area same all the times `0x391904c8606da7e9:0xd70a28b88f7720d7`

so can I get the Location information (Lat, Long) from Feature ID of Search Area is there any API or SDK available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before March 31, 2017 according linked by you [Stop Worrying About the New Google Maps; These URL Parameters Are Gold](https://moz.com/blog/new-google-maps-url-parameters) article of [David Mihm](https://moz.com/community/users/439609) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35152580/6950238) question of [Martin Larsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3615656/martin-larsen) you can look up the Feature ID on Google Mapmaker like this:

`http://www.google.com/mapmaker?gw=39&fid=0x391904c8606da7e9:0xd70a28b88f7720d7`

But since March 31, 2017 [Google Map Maker officially closed](https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/7195127), and many of its features are being integrated into Google Maps. So use [Google Maps Android Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps&hl=en) for open URLs with Feature IDs in external app, or `HttpUrlConnection` (and `WebView`) like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54118244/6950238) answer to open them in your application.